# How to display Jquery datatable information in print view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables, frontend

I want to include datatable information in the print view.

**Example I want to show this information in the print view: Showing 1 to 9 of 9 entries**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've just played with the print option myself to see if I can wing it; including the footer didn't do much but add the same  footer to the bottom of the table in print view; however; if you use the custom message you may be able to produce a good result; you can for example set a custom message showing total entries above or below your printed document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                messageBottom: function () {
                    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
                    var info = oTable.page.info();
                    var count = info.recordsTotal;
                    return 'Showing total entries of ' + count;
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
});
```

You can play with either messageBottom or messageTop; or display both with two different messages.

Comment: Thanks for the help your code gave me hint to get what I wanted which was to show the number of filtered rows against the total number of rows in the table and for that, I just included: var rowCount = $('.table >tbody >tr').length; in your code which gave me the number of filtered rows.

Comment: Awesome, happy I was able to point you in the right direction